# Citus "... is a metadata node, but is out of sync HINT: If the node is up, wait until metadata gets synced to it and try again."

Tags: database, postgresql-13, citus

I've got a Citus (v10.1) sharded PostgreSQL (v13) cluster with 4 nodes. Master node address is 10.0.0.2 and the rest are up to .5 When trying to manage my sharded table, I've got this error:

> ERROR: 10.0.0.5:5432 is a metadata node, but is out of sync
> HINT:  If the node is up, wait until metadata gets synced to it and try again.

I've been waiting. After 30 minutes or more, I've literally did `drop schema ... cascade`, `drop extension Citus cascade;` and after re-importing the data, creating a shard I've got the same error message once more and can't get past it.

#### Some additional info:

Another thing that might be an actual hint is I cannot distribute my function through create_distributed_function(), because it's says it in a DeadLock state, and transaction cannot be committed.

I've checked idle processes, nothing out of ordinary.

Created shard like that:

```
SELECT create_distributed_table('test_table', 'id');
SELECT alter_distributed_table('test_table', shard_count:=128, cascade_to_colocated:=true);
```

There is no topic in google search result regarding this subject.

###### EDIT 1:

I did bomb (20k-200k hits per second) my shard with a huge amount of requests for a function that does insert/update or delete if specific argument is set.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather strange error. It might be the case that you hit the issue in https://github.com/citusdata/citus/issues/4721

Do you have column defaults that are generated by sequences? If so, consider using bigserial types for these columns.

If it does not work, you can disable metadata syncing by `SELECT stop_metadata_sync)to_node('10.0.0.5','5432')` optionally followed by `SELECT start_metadata_sync_to_node('10.0.0.5','5432')` to stop waiting for metadata syncing and (optionally) retry metadata creation from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm unable to check if this answer is helpful, because I'm no longer working near this project. 
I must say, that I did google for `stop_metadata_sync` just now, and it's literały nowhere, so huge kudos for you, for making internet aware of this function! 
Also I did not had any defaults there, but it could be a big int issue, because I did generated them as a timestamps (don't ask why, I had to :) ) and they were huge.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. We (Citus Engine team at Microsoft) do not monitor SO very closely. The next time you have an issue with Citus, you can consider writing in our slack channel where we try to answer all questions in <24 hours. 

https://slack.citusdata.com/